# Java or C++ API for Apache Drill

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, apache-drill

I want to access Drill through a programming interface. The Apache Drill documentation just mentions about its JAVA and C++ libraries for the client to connect but doesn't provide any documentation or example for the same.

http://drill.apache.org/faq/#what-clients-are-supported?

http://drill.apache.org/docs/architecture-introduction/#drill-clients

The closest thing which I was able to find on the forums/documentations was to connect through the drill-JDBC driver. But it defeats the purpose of what I want to do. Does anyone has any idea where I can find more about these APIs and if they are actually there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They provide native C++ [client](https://github.com/apache/drill/tree/master/contrib/native/client).

Check querySubmitter [example](https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/contrib/native/client/example/querySubmitter.cpp) for more details.